# Building regular expressions

Tags: regex

I need to build a regular expression, which is going to be used in a Google Analytics filter. The regular expression needs to capture all of following strings:

> /webshop?product=bil, /webshop?product=indbo, /webshop?product=hus,
>   /webshop?seksjon=product, /webshop?product=ulykke

I've tried building several regex s but no luck this time. Can someone help?

Comment: use something like https://rubular.com/ and you'll get instant feedback on what works and not. Then come back here with a more detailed question when you are stuck. Post input and expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: `.*` matches all of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code. you could modify as required

```
(\/webshop\?(?:product|seksjon)\=\w+)
```

Verify result [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5C%2Fwebshop%5C%3F(%3F%3Aproduct%7Cseksjon)%5C%3D%5Cw%2B)&test_string=%2Fwebshop%3Fproduct%3Dbil%2C%20%2Fwebshop%3Fproduct%3Dindbo%2C%20%2Fwebshop%3Fproduct%3Dhus%2C%20%2Fwebshop%3Fseksjon%3Dproduct%2C%20%2Fwebshop%3Fproduct%3Dulykke&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)